# How can one conditionally Replace some selected columns in Powerquery

Tags: powerquery

I have a set of data and i wish to REPLACE some column(s) that contains values  1, 1, F adjacent to each other.
whenever powerquery sees these set of  three columns adjacent to each other containing 1,1, F respectively.I want it to replace the group of columns in that set of values to say 0, 0, *
i know how to replace values with another value, buh i want just whenever the occurence of these values showed, to get it replaced in set.
I have been strongly to resolve  these for sometimes buh to no avail.

Click here and see the challenge:

https://ibb.co/Bf3zGRn

Thank you.

Comment: your title says delete, question is about modify. you should change title

Comment: @horseyride ,I have just changed the title .Can this bulk replace whenever 1,1, F occur in my dataset?

Comment: And what if i have the dataset where Camth is also 1 .example,camth=1 examth=1,mth=1 and mthgrade=F .can also use thesame method you use here.   ?

Comment: Yes.  Same method would apply

Comment: @horseyride thank you so much.  i shall mark the green button soon as solved.    I have another challenge,how do i  manipulate this figure as shown in this challenge :
  https://ibb.co/zH2RXRz                                                                                            
                                                              what i want is in this url :      https://ibb.co/98HMCJj

Comment: Im not sure what you want to manipulate that is any different .  If you are using my method, then just refer to whatever columns you want to test using [TheColumnNameHere] and with "TheColumnNameHere" in the replace formula

Comment: i do not what to use pivoting because, some of these dataset are data imported from the web,pivot will remove nulls values. These nulls are data to be filled later The Column date is sorted in descending order, so that the latest records is kept while the previous records are discarded. This like remove duplicates and keep the latest records.I have this query solved before buh the solutions, had some performance issues.  This is a different question entirely..i am glad you have been able to help to resolve challenge no1.

Comment: I am not using pivoting. I am not sure why that is mentioned

Comment: @ horseyride, your solution works perfectly , thank you, however, The second question i raised was a different question entirely...May be someone else could tackle the challenge

Comment: If you have a different question, start a different question. Thanks.

Comment: However, to check for all the columns, for this condition, should i have to keep adding custom columns   ?

Comment: You can just extend out the formula in one column if ([exammth] = 1 and [mth] =1 and  [mthgrde] ="F") or ([examt33] = 3 and [mr23rth] =1 and  [mthgrde] ="C") then "b" else "a"    but if there is a bunch of these then you need to re-write your question to actually ask what you intended

Comment: OK, thank you. I shall create another topic for the second question raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step replaces the values of specified columns with 0, where the specified condition is met:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step", each [exammth] = 1 and [mth] = 1 and [mthgrade] = "F", 0, (x,y,z)=> if y then z else x, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous Step"), each List.Contains({"exammth","mth","mthgrade"},_)))
```

Comment: what if you have four column headers to search through..example, camth=1, exammth=1, mth=1, mthgrade=F , how do i  replace it to zeros

Comment: `= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step", each [camth] = 1 and [exammth] = 1 and [mth] = 1 and [mthgrade] = "F", 0, (x,y,z)=> if y then z else x, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous Step"), each List.Contains({"camth","exammth","mth","mthgrade"},_)))`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i was just asking for other columns , on the powerquery table. i have gotten what i what anyway ..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with complicated formula, but simple way to do what you want is:

Add column .. custom column .. with formula to test those 3 columns

```
if [exammth] = 1 and [mth] =1 and  [mthgrde] ="F" then "b" else "a"
```

filter for the **b**s using the arrows atop the column

right click and transform the three columns to become 0,0,*
For the numericals, choose any transform function then change the formula to be **each 0**, for the alpha column use **each "*"**

recombine with the original data, filtered for the **a**s

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Class", type text}, {"camth", Int64.Type}, {"exammth", Int64.Type}, {"mth", Int64.Type}, {"mthgrde", type text}, {"caecons", Int64.Type}, {"examecons", Int64.Type}, {"ecpms", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [exammth] = 1 and [mth] =1 and  [mthgrde] ="F" then "b" else "a"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = "b")),
Replace1 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"exammth", each 0, Int64.Type}}),
Replace2 = Table.TransformColumns(Replace1,{{"mth", each 0, Int64.Type}}),
Replace3 = Table.TransformColumns(Replace2,{{"mthgrde", each "*", type text}}),
combined = Replace3 &  Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = "a") )
in  combined
```

[image]